# SSH over softether VPN connection

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, raspberry-pi

I configured my Raspberry Pi as a softether VPN server (according to [Raspberry Pi: Install a SSTP VPN server using SoftEther](https://jlnostr.de/en/blog/raspberry-pi-sstp-vpn-server-installieren)).

I can now create a VPN connection from my Windows machine to the Raspberry. The Windows machine gets the VPN-IP 192.168.30.10 and the Raspberry has the VPN-IP 192.168.30.1. Pinging the Raspberry (ping 192.168.30.1) works, but I can not establish a SSH connection to the Raspberry over this VPN network.

How can I configure softether to forward/accept SSH traffic on port 22?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to use the SoftEther VPN Client for Windows and enable `SecureNAT` on the VPN server. With this configuration no "port forwarding" needs to be enabled on the server.